# No speakers available as soon as headphones are in Dell XPS 15

Tags: sound, dell, headphones, 18.10, xps

I am experiencing problems with the audio device on my Dell XPS 15. The differentiation between headphone jack and laptop speakers fails. When no headphones are plugged in the speakers work fine. When headphones are plugged in only they will work, but it has no effect to set the laptop speakers as output in the sound settings. They remain quiet whatsoever.

Is this a known problem? Any way to make both output types selectable while the headphone jack is plugged in?

Comment: It depends on hardware. Most likely it is not possible to solve.

Comment: Usually, there are ways of fixing this. There is usually two ways of doing this. Either have both of them working at the same time, or making a switch so that you can manually choose, on pulse audio, whether you want the sound coming out of the speakers of through the headphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laptop has only one sound card channel meaning that headphones and speakers are basically connected to the same output, but when you connect your headphones your speakers automatically get disconnected. And there is nothing you can do since this is a mechanical switch in the jack or it is electrically sensing if you have plugged in your headphones. The only way you could have multiple sound outputs is to add a USB sound card to get another jack.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Is it specific to Dell XPS 15, or Dell in general? Because in every computer and laptop I've ever owned the switch is purely on the software side (ALSA), so you can definitely play with it.

Comment: It isn't specific to dell my hp works the same so like I said you could get USB to 3.5mmm adapter and it should work fine then.

Comment: I just tried with Windows and I got the same result, so you're probably right. I awarded you the bounty, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help you.